# Most popular Youtube channels based on subscriptions

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is there a way to get a list of most popular Youtube channels based on their subscriptions?

I am using Youtube API v3.

With "Search" i only get most popular Youtube channels based on their viewcount?

With "Channels:list" i am wondering whats the order of those channels?

Is there something similar to this in V3 ?https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_feeds

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [**ChannelSections**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channelSections) Class

> A `channelSection` resource contains information about a set of videos that a channel has chosen to feature. For example, a section could feature a channel's latest uploads, most popular uploads, or videos from one or more playlists.

You will be checking the

snippet.type property subscriptions

You can also check the [Implementation and Migration: Videos](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/videos#videos-retrieve-uploads), to check if some `v2` function can still be implemented in `v3`.

I hope this helps